# jQuery namespace collisions with Bootstrap 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, bootstrap-5

I have taken the plunge learning jQuery and Bootstrap.  I however, learnt that Bootstrap 4 is happy with jQuery being used, but the latest version (v5.1.3) doesn't always. That is because, as [InfoQ points out](https://www.infoq.com/news/2020/08/bootsrap-5-drops-jquery/) that the Bootstrap team noted that all supported browsers provide jQuery replacement features in plain JavaScript and therefore they saved 85KB in minified JavaScript.

[Bootstrap.com points out that](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/javascript/#still-want-to-use-jquery-its-possible)

> Bootstrap 5 is designed to be used without jQuery, but it’s still possible to use our components with jQuery. If Bootstrap detects `jQuery` in the `window` object it’ll add all of our components in jQuery’s plugin system; this means you’ll be able to do `$('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()` to enable tooltips. The same goes for our other components.

However, confusingly it points out that **(emphasis mine)**

> Due to browser limitations, some of our plugins, **namely Dropdown, Tooltip and Popover plugins, cannot be used** in a `<script>` tag with `module` type because they depend on Popper.

[Bootstrap.com also points out that](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/javascript/#no-conflict-only-if-you-use-jquery)

> **No conflict (only if you use jQuery)**
> Sometimes it is necessary to use Bootstrap plugins with other UI frameworks. In these circumstances, namespace collisions can occasionally occur. If this happens, you may call `.noConflict` on the plugin you wish to revert the value of.

Do this mean that jQuery has namespace collisions which need to be borne in mind?  What reliable resource is available for highlighting these collisions?

Comment: So I think what this is @ChrisRogers is that you have a regular CDN link for Bootstrap v5.x and then if you look in the docs you also have a CDN link for Bootstrap Bundle. The first one means you have to add tooltips and popovers yourself using something like Popper.js but, in the second one, the Bundle, Popper is included. This is all really just to avoid having to use Popper by default when it might not be needed and therefor reduce the amount of JS. Here are the details https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/